# Windows server 2019 blue screen - HAL_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019

For third time in 2 weeks we have got a blue screen *HAL_INITIALIZATION_FAILED* message on our Windows Server 2019 VM running in VMWare.

After we reset the VM the system loads without any problem. We have researched all kinds of logs (Windows event, VMWare logs, and so on) but there is no trace of the blue screen event or why it's happening.

Some aditional info:

- We did notice that the blue screen event seems to be happening at the
  same time (aprox 2 am).
- At the moment of the blue screen no user is logged or active on the
  server.
- Our server is running a web application.
- After the reeboot of the server via VMWare the server starts normally without a problem.

**Update**
Dump from WinDBG
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the output of WinDBG when you performed the analysis on the memory dump that was created?

Comment: If you see `.dmp` files in `%SystemRoot%\Minidump` with the right time-stamp, please publish them online for us (OneDrive, Dropbox etc). Question: Are Windows and your drivers fully updated? Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and also `chkdsk`.

Comment: SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine+a5

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

STACK_COMMAND:  .cxr; .ecxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  a5

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x5C_HAL_TIMER_VPPT_ARMING_FAILURE_nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine

OS_VERSION:  10.0.17763.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs5_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {b436b37e-5eb7-47d3-6a75-34a3dd40c9e6}

Followup:     MachineOwner

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_JQ7FCAjKYhuxGUy_gskj1G0ktTcYDXD/view?usp=drive_link here is the dump file

Comment: Your DMP file is unusable for some reason. HAL_INITIALIZATION_FAILED normally means a hardware error, but is unusual in a VM. Have you installed any new drivers in the VM or did recently any Windows Update? Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Is there anything running around that time in Task Scheduler?

Comment: What version of VMWare? There is some more troubleshooting here: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/HAL-INITIALIZATION-FAILED-Windows-Server-2019/td-p/2948542. With a VM, the error is related to issues with the CPU clock, so usually something with vmtools, host cpu problems, snapshots, or some incompatibility.